# FB.login() causes Error 191 in any IE (Internet Exploder)

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have searched this problem for long now but all answers have not worked so far.

The code that calls for login:

```
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

            document.getElementById("nimi").value = response.name;
            document.getElementById("email").value = response.email;

            FB.ui(
              {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                attachment: {
                  name: 'Jõulupidu Maikrahv restoranis!',
                  caption: 'Broneeri firma jõulupidu hubases Maikrahv restoranis! Kingime Uusaasta pidulaua 10- le ja romantilise õhtusöögi kahele! ',
                  media: [
                        { 
                            "type": "image", 
                            "src": "http://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/maikrahv.jpg",
                            "href": https+"://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/"
                        }]
                },
                href: https+'://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/',
                action_links: [
                  { text: 'Maikrahv', href: https+"://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/" }
                ]
              },
              function(response) {    
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        var ajaxresp = jagame_fbajax();
                    } else {
                        fb_alert("Teade!", "Postitust ei jagatud ja ei osale loosimises.");
                    }
              }
            );

        });
      } else {
        fb_alert("Viga!", "Kuna õiguseid ei jagatud, ei saanud Sind osalemises kahjuks kirja panna")    
      }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
    }
```

Only IE gives this error

An error occurred with Jõulupidu Maikrahvis. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Antud URL ei ole rakenduse konfiguratsiooni poolt lubatud.

Application settings:

```
App Domain: advert.ee ssl.advert.ee
Website: 
   Siute URL: http://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/
App on Facebook: 
   Canvas URL: http://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/
   Secure Cavas URL: https://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/
   Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/maikrahv-joulupidu
Page Tab:
   Page Tab Name: Jõulupidu Maikrahvis!
   Page Tab URL: http://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/
   Secure Page Tab URL: https://ssl.advert.ee/maikrahv-joulupidu/
```

Reported bug also:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258868920826496

Please help. App must go live tomorrow :(

Answer (score 1):

remove the channelUrl parameter from the fb init.  IE reads the javascript incorrectly and puts the channel URL in the redirect_uri query var and it breaks the whole process.

Comment: Isn't the channel URL specifically for IE so it doesn't load the SDK twice?

Answer (score 1):

Jacob rights.

I put this code:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
        FB.init({      
            appId      : 'APP_ID',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true,
            xfbml      : true 
        });
    } else {
        FB.init({      
            appId      : APP_ID,
            channelUrl : '//example.com/channel.php', // Channel File
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true,
            xfbml      : true 
        });
    }
```

and solved the problem.