# Facebook javascript login error in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm doing a ASP.NET WebForms App with FB login.
I'm using the latest Facebook C# SDK, and based on theirs example to login.
I've using sandbox mode, and the web app is with fixed port.

In IE 9, when I click in the button, I've the facebook response: "An error occurred with YourApp. Please try again later.", but if I use Chrome or Firefox everything goes right (I can login, and have a response to my web app).

I've search where trying to find a solution, but nothing fits... :(

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL contains the port number like "**http://domain.com:7071/TestApp**", It does not work in IE. Try to host your application with no port and check. It will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this:

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

I have had to set the P3P headers before now to get around the problem you are facing.

Comment: If I generate the P3P policy, when I deploy the web app, I to add the same policy, right? I'm new at this stuf...

Comment: You need to make sure that your headers in each page response contains something like this: HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("P3P:CP", "IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT");

Answer (score 1):

Try sending this as a HTTP Header:

```
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"
```

Comment: I try to add the `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("p3p", "CP=\"NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP\"");` in my login page, and the problem maintains... :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had similar issue.

Either comment out your channel Url or do like this guy
[FB.login() causes Error 191 in any IE (Internet Exploder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407708/fb-login-causes-error-191-in-any-ie-internet-exploder)

IE does not understand the channelURL and puts it in your login url.

Comment: With localhost:port in IE doesn't work, but if you use another borwser works.
When you move to production all will work! :)

Answer (score 0):

disable sandbox mode in your app setting. If you enable it then the app is only visible for admin so disable...